# Add a class to a fixed div when

Tags: jquery, html

I have a fixed div and I want to add a class to it, when it is over another div completely. I have managed to do add the class based on when the second div comes to the top but it is not quite what I want as I want to add the class based on which div is underneath it.

```js
var distance = $('.Section-2').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
         $(".hamburger-box").addClass('orange');
    }
 else {
  $(".hamburger-box").removeClass('orange');
 }
  });
```

```css
.hamburger-box {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.Section-1 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}

.Section-2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}

.orange {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger-box">

</div>

<div class="Section-1">

</div>

<div class="Section-2">

</div>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what _"but it is not quite what I want"_ means. At what point should the div change color? When the underlying, scrolling div touches it, is completely under it, etc? Also, post a [mcve] in your question, not on a third party site.

Comment: Added the code and I want the fixed div to be completely over the other div

Comment: You might want to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

You can minus offset the hamburger box height like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8er5yz2o/)

```
var distance = $('.Section-2').offset().top - $('.hamburger-box').outerHeight(),
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
         $(".hamburger-box").addClass('orange');
    }
    else {
        $(".hamburger-box").removeClass('orange');
    }
  });
```